# SQL Server 2000 control process priority

Tags: sql-server, process

Is it possible to control the execution priority of SQL Server processes?

Suppose you have a db with some large tables, with many users executing queries, and you have to create an index on one large table. The indexing process may run with low priority and CPU usage, while interactive users may have higher priority and CPU usage.

Is it possible to tune the process priority either for a single process or a process category?

Comment: Not really programming-related --> better move this to Serverfault.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is nothing similar in MSSQL until version 2008, which has a "Resource Governor" (but it's only available in Enterprise Edition).